Inserting a vertical line on an underscore
I would like to add a vertical line 'on' an underscore.  Consider the 10 underscores below.

How can I place a vertical line 'on' the underscore.  e.g.

Thanks in advance.

Your question sounds very unclear for me. Could you please add a minimal working example (MWE)?

@jlab Perhaps he wants to create a table (see tag tables) or a matrix (math-mode) where each element contains an underscore and a vertical bar.

I just wanted a vertical line above a horizontal line (maybe an underscore) in the minimal amount of Latex code.  I could use a table, but thought that was overkill.

@Stephan Do you want a gap between the vertical and horizontal line or may they touch?

I prefer a gap - just so it is easier to read.  Thanks

The command \series (choose a better name) has two arguments:

the number of underscores
the list of underscores that should receive the vertical line

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\series}{mm}
 {% #1 = number of underscores
  % #2 = places with |
  \stephan_series:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__stephan_series_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__stephan_series_item:N
 {
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\depth-0.3ex}}{\underline{\makebox[0.75em]{#1{$\shortmid$}}}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stephan_series:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__stephan_series_seq
  \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
   {
    \clist_if_in:nnTF {#2} {##1}
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__stephan_series_seq { \__stephan_series_item:N \use:n }
     }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__stephan_series_seq { \__stephan_series_item:N \phantom }
     }
   }
   \mbox{\seq_use:Nn \l__stephan_series_seq {~}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

aaa \series{10}{4} bbb

aaa \series{10}{1,3,5,8} bbb

\end{document}



Maybe you could use \clap to superpose characters in the center of a fixed width box
\makebox[1em][c]{%
 \clap{\_}%
 \clap{\rule[0.1em]{0.1ex}{0.5em}}}%
}

Define a command for that
\NewDocumentCommand{\something}{ s }{%
  \makebox[1em][c]{%
    \clap{\_}%
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\clap{\rule[0.1em]{0.1ex}{0.5em}}}%
  }%
}

(a better name should be found). The starred variant produce the vertical line.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\something}{ s }{%
  \makebox[1em][c]{%
    \clap{\_}%
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\clap{\rule[0.1em]{0.1ex}{0.5em}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\something\something\something\something\something\something\something\something\something\something

\something\something\something*\something\something\something\something\something\something\something

\something\something\something*\something\something*\something*\something*\something\something\something


\end{document}



Thanks.... That's what I was after.  I have never come across the \clap command.

@Stephan If you need it for math, the mathtools package provides the \mathclap command. There are also \rlap/\mathrlap (align right) and \llap/\lmathap (align left).
